# Why is my code not calculating the gradient of x?

Tags: python

When I run the following code, I get an Attribute Error on the line 'sign_gradient = gradient.sign()' saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sign'. It doesn't appear to be calculating the grad of x, it only calculates the grad of loss.

```
epsilon = 0.1
x.requires_grad = True

output = model(x, y)
loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, y)

loss.requires_grad = True
loss.backward()

gradient = x.grad
sign_gradient = gradient.sign()
```

I've tried a few things such as calling x.retains_grad() before loss.backward(), using gradient = output.grad thinking it might have calculated the gradient of that instead but I get the same error on both. I can't get it to compute the gradient of anything other than loss.

Comment: x is not defined, model is not defined, torch is not defined

Comment: What are the values of `output ` and `loss`, are they are what you expect? Try dumping them.

Comment: `x.grad` is None.  Simple as that.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)